# Turnstile antennas with a "single-point feed": what's the antenna theory behind this, and how do I build/model it?

Tags: antenna-theory, antenna-construction, uhf, satellites, circular-polarization

The conventional turnstile antenna uses a 1/4wl phasing line between the crossed elements, to get the required phase shift. 4nec2 includes an example file, though, of a circularly-polarized Yagi using a "single-point feed" (Google brings up few results for this term--it comes from the notes in the NEC file). It consists of two crossed dipoles connected to one feedpoint, in the same manner as you would build a simple wire bowtie antenna, except that one dipole is longer than the other. There's also a commercial turnstile antenna, the WiMo TA-1, which uses a single-point feed and differing-length dipoles (OZ9AEC wrote a review of it with a good photo illustrating the differing element lengths and physically connected feedpoints).

Last night I modeled up a 70cm single-point fed turnstile in 4nec2, with no reflectors or directors, bare 12ga copper wire, using the optimizer to find the right element lengths for a good RHCP pattern. I built it, went out to listen to FO-29's 70cm beacon, and was disappointed: the signal faded pretty deeply as I rotated the antenna. For reference: I built it using the exact same gap at the feedpoint as my model (22mm), with three FT50-43s at the feedpoint to at least pay lip service to reducing common-mode current. My model predicted 1.8:1 SWR, but I have no way to measure SWR above 2m, so I can't check this.

Here are the actual questions: is there an established name for this kind of turnstile antenna, with what I'm calling a "single-point feed?" Are there any equations/empirical methods for designing them? From an antenna-theory perspective, why do they work?

Comment: seems to be the same as any phased stacked antenna...except that it's 90 degrees physically out of phase instead of in phase.